# Why is $\left.\frac {-1} {s+a} e^{-(s+a)t}\right\vert_{t=0}^{t=\infty}= \frac 1 {s+a}$ and that the ROC is: $\operatorname{Re}(s+a)>0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

I know this is a self study question, but help would be much of appreciated. I don’t know why this is true.

> For complex $s, a$, show that: 
>   $$\left.\frac {-1} {s+a} e^{-(s+a)t}\right\vert_{t=0}^{t=\infty}=\frac 1 {s+a}$$ and that the region of convergance is: $\operatorname{Re}(s+a)>0$

Comment: Are you sure it is not $e^{\color{red}-(s+a)t}$ ? Also, use \vert instead of \vline, _ instead of \from and ^ instead of \to

Comment: One second I’m correcting. I downloaded the app and I misused it...

Comment: I am also still not sure if this is true. I mean it could go off to $\infty$ if $s$ and $a$ are chosen apropriately. The correct command for $\infty$ is \infty

Comment: Indeed. Corrected. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Use the fact that $\exp(0)=1$ and $\exp(c t)\xrightarrow{t\to\infty}0$ for all complex numbers $c$ with real part $<0$

Comment: The second part is true because then the radius strives to minus infinity? Can I answer my own question if I get this right (with your help)?

Comment: Sure, go ahead and answer your own question! Here is what I would say: $$|\exp(c t)|=|\exp(\operatorname{Re}(c)t)\exp(\operatorname{Im}(c)t)|=C \exp(\operatorname{Re}(c)t)\to0$$ (where $C= |\exp(\operatorname{Im}(c)t)|$ is a constant)

Comment: Ok, I got it now (sorry after looking at this questions again, I understand how simple it is). -exp(a+s) AND 1/a+s are both have the same type of convergence (for a+s). Sorry. Simple it is. Many thanks for your patience and to anyone who wanted and didn’t downvote this question.

Comment: OK I apologies, I corrected again the question. The region of convergence wasn’t given and needed to be found and this is what confused me. I understand a+s shall be greater than 0, but I don’t understand how complex number can be greater than another number by anything but the radius of it :/.